# I am using BIOS J51 v01.35 on which version is on intel TM i5

Tags: linux, bios

My system is  Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-2500 CPU @ 3.30GHz

and bios is version J51 v01.35

release data of bios 01/10/2012

So Should I believe I am using SMBIOS 2 or SMBios 3

On wiki.Osdev there are no docs for version 3 but there are for version 2 for SMBIOS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find this information using `dmidecode`:

```
# dmidecode
...
Getting SMBIOS data from sysfs.
SMBIOS 2.7 present.
285 structures occupying 19154 bytes.
Table at 0x0EFC201F.
...
```

Comment: what is `Table at 0x0EFC201F.` thing is this the start of SMBIOS entry point table

Comment: That is the location of the table of SMBIOS structures on my system.  Yours will probably be different.  Read the `dmidecode` man page for more information.

Comment: I believe its a virtual address. Can I find physical address with dmidecode?

Comment: @user786. No, there is no option within dmicode to do so.